# select newest update record among similar record

Tags: postgresql, datetime, join, select, postgresql-9.1

I have  2 tables segments and summaries.
I want to list the shows in a date interval and just show the latest updated segments (in bold) since it is the freshest copy of the segment for that person.
Here is the query I used to have the result below:

```
select seg.summ, su.channel, seg.block_id, seg.person, seg.updated_at as segupdate 
from segments seg 
   left join summaries su on seg.summ = su.id 
where su.created_at between '2018-06-06' and '2018-07-13' 
order by summ, block_id, seg.updated_at desc;
```

[image]

I want this:

[image]

How can I get change my query to show just the bolded rows? to remove the duplicates that are an older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did :

```
select distinct on (seg.summ, seg.block_id, seg.person) su.channel, seg.updated_at as segupdate 
from segments seg 
  left join summaries su on seg.summ = su.id 
where su.created_at between '2018-06-06' and '2018-07-13' 
order by summ, block_id, person, seg.updated_at desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function, make row number `order by segupdate DESC`, then get `rn = 1` newest data row.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY summ,channel,block_id,person order by segupdate DESC) rn
     FROM (
        select seg.summ, su.channel, seg.block_id, seg.person, seg.updated_at as segupdate 
         from segments seg 
         left join summaries su on seg.summ = su.id 
         where su.created_at between '2018-06-06' and '2018-07-13' 
     ) t1
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Comment: There is no duplicate but i is selecting the oldest instead of the newest.